# Why are top/bottom boxplot whiskers crooked?

Tags: matlab, plot, boxplot

Created a box plot of (non-Gaussian) variable W_BP, and changed whisker length to encompass 1st to 99th percentile.  Problem is, the top and bottom of each whisker are crooked.  Suggestions as to how to fix?  Code and image below:

[image: Sample_Box_Plot]

```
clc;
clear all;

% load datafile
load TRMM_Tropics_regression_data_pt_1mmhr_2004.mat;

whos

p = prctile(W_BP,[1,99]);
figure;
boxplot(W_BP,'whisker',2.5,'outliersize',2);
hold on;

% replace upper end y value of whisker
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Whisker'));
for j = 1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(2) = p(2,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Adjacent Value'));
for j = 1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(2) = p(2,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% replace lower end y value of whisker
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Whisker'));
for j = 1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(1) = p(1,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Adjacent Value'));
for j = 1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(1) = p(1,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
t = title('TRMM-3B42 Cluster Area vs Cluster Power, Tropics (RR GTE 0.1mmhr), May-Sep 2004');
set(t, 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 10)
set(gca, 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 14)
set(gca, 'YLim',[10^0 10^6])
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
xlabel('Bin Number');
ylabel('Cluster Power (GW)');
print -dpng Sample_Boxplot.png
```

Comment: Please either provide the data, or even better make up a simplified example that doesn't need external data.

Comment: Contentwise: Well, you manipulate the whiskers to this effect. If you don't want skewed whiskers, don't mess with them?

Comment: Happy to provide the data...how can I attach a .mat file?

Comment: You have to find some filesharing site, and then include the link in the question. SO itself does not have facilities for this. Or, if there are not too many values, you can post code that generates the variables. But actually I'd recommend you find a simpler version that doesn't need data. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve